# Can I use Fitbit Api to get the acceleration data of my Fitbit?

Tags: java, api, accelerometer, sensors, fitbit

I'm trying to use data from my Fitbit to catch my hand movement.

Then I find the Fitbit Api here: https://wiki.fitbit.com/display/API/Fitbit+Resource+Access+API

In the collection resources part, it seems that I can only get some data like body measurements, weight, recent activities, friends, etc.

So, my question is, does Fitbit provide any API to help me get its realtime accelerometer data and Gyroscope data?

Answer (score 0):

No, based on my research and contact with company, they do not provide raw accelerometer data.

[See here.](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/fitbit-api/yt5pESdF7UY)

Comment: I remember reading about this, and it's because recording accelerometer data takes too much battery power, and it's more efficient to make step-detection logic into an IC.

Comment: More evidence that it's a "no" - https://community.fitbit.com/t5/Web-API-Development/Get-the-raw-accelerometer-data/m-p/390004#M298